# MTL4: umfpack.h not found

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile

I'm trying to install the MTL4 library (https://gitlab.mn.tu-dresden.de/spraetor/mtl4.git):

```
$ cd mtl4
$ mkdir build
$ cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=./build -B build_dir -S .
$ cmake --build build_dir --target install
```

After this I get the following error message:

```
[  0%] Building CXX object libs/numeric/mtl/test/CMakeFiles/PA_test.dir/PA_test.cpp.o
In file included from /home/user/Downloads/mtl4/build/mtl4/boost/numeric/mtl/operations.hpp:111,
                 from /home/user/Downloads/mtl4/build/mtl4/boost/numeric/mtl/mtl.hpp:17,
                 from /home/user/Downloads/mtl4/build/mtl4/libs/numeric/mtl/test/PA_test.cpp:14:
/home/user/Downloads/mtl4/build/mtl4/boost/numeric/mtl/interface/umfpack_solve.hpp:36:12: fatal error: umfpack.h: No such file or directory
   36 | #  include <umfpack.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [libs/numeric/mtl/test/CMakeFiles/PA_test.dir/build.make:76: libs/numeric/mtl/test/CMakeFiles/PA_test.dir/PA_test.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1719: libs/numeric/mtl/test/CMakeFiles/PA_test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
```

I use Archlinux, I previously installed the `suitesparse` package, which, as I understand it, provides a header file `umfpack.h`.

Comment: Clearly your compiler disagrees. Where on your system is `umfpack.h` located? The `suitesparse` package installs it under `/usr/include/suitesparse`, which is not where your compiler looks by default. Use the `-I` flag to tell your compiler to look there as well. The Ubuntu package also puts the header under that directory.

Comment: Clear your cache. And reach out to the MTL4 developers, that they should add proper checks for dependencies.

Comment: @usr1234567 .. Like checking for umpack.h with a [suitable hint to the probable location](https://gitlab.mn.tu-dresden.de/spraetor/mtl4/-/blob/master/tools/cmake/UMFPACK.cmake#L6)?